# Calculus II: The sum of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

I have this math problem and I'm not entirely sure how to set it up.

It is know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}=\frac{n}{2^n}=2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{n2^n}=ln(2)$. Supposing that $a, b, $and $c$ are constants, evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{an^2+cn+b}{n2^n}$.

I know I have to use both the sums that were given, however I'm not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Because the sums converge (separately) you can sum them and get the same result

HINT $2$: If $\underset{{n \to \infty}}{\lim} b_n = b$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n + a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n + \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = a + b$$

Sol:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{an^2+cn+b}{n2^n} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{an^2}{n2^n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{cn}{n2^n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{b}{n2^n} = 2a + c -1 + b\log(2)$$

Comment: Do you mean sum up both sums? So like $2+ln(2)$?

Comment: No, you can separate the terms of the series, that is the sums in the term $(an^2 + cn +b)$

Comment: @KFC See the second hint

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about splitting it up?